# Is there a way to automatically import data into a form field in Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Tags: pdf, import, adobe, acrobat

I'm open to other solutions as well.

My issue is this.  We have about 500+ and growing different PDFs that need to have certain information (company info, phone numbers, etc.) added to form fields dynamically.  The reason this needs to be dynamic is that this information changes regularly and we do not want to have to update all 500 PDFs each time it changes.  So I am looking for some way to set up the PDFs so that they all read from a single external source (could be something as simple as a text file) dynamically upon opening the PDF in Acrobat Pro.

I have done some on-the-fly PDF creation in the past through PHP, however this does not seem like the best solution here as the PDFs need to be edited a lot by non-programmers and such.  I'd prefer not to go that route and just stick to finding a way to get a few lines of data into the PDFs they create.

I've researched this a bit and it seems... possible, but confusing?  This is the best thing I could find so far:

http://www.pdfscripting.com/public/department48.cfm

But the three solutions that it offers near the bottom all sound convoluted.  Just wondering if there is something simpler that I am missing.  All I really need to do is have the PDF import a few small chunks of text.  Seems like it should be easy...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/679606/Filling-PDF-Form-using-iText-PDF-Library a try. Hopefully it fulfills your needs.